# Name for right angle triangle within a unit circle (hypotenuse=1)

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking for the name of the right angled triangles drawn within the so called unit circle. Ie any right angle with hypotenuse of 1. Is there a name for them? Or at least a concise name? I'm regularly referring to them and saying "right angle triangle with a hypotenuse of one" is seriously verbose.

Comment: "Unit right triangle"?

Comment: @blue I googled that and it seemed results only referred to "unit" in conjunction with circle, rather than describing that class of triangles. Alternatively, it referred to triangles where one side was 1, not the hypotenuse

Comment: If you're only (or primarily) considering triangles in the unit circle, one alternative is to establish this convention (e.g., "All right triangles are assumed to have unit hypotenuse unless explicitly specified otherwise"), and to refresh the reader's memory at decent intervals. (I do like Blue's suggestion, though.)